# Ajax - variables are seen in chrome network tab but they don't seem to pass to the PHP function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to update a php function using ajax.
I Have an array stored in localstorage. 
The array contains values of clicked  id's.

When I click the `<tr>`, the array gets updated and sent via ajax from a js file to the php file.

js file

```
function storeId(id) {
    var ids = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('reportArray')) || [];

    if (ids.indexOf(id) === -1) {
        ids.push(id);
        localStorage.setItem('reportArray', JSON.stringify(ids));
    }else{
        //remove id from array
        var index = ids.indexOf(id);
        if (index > -1) {
            ids.splice(index, 1);
        }
        localStorage.setItem('reportArray', JSON.stringify(ids));
    }
    return id;
}

//ajax function
$('table tr').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        storeId(id);
        var selected_lp = localStorage.getItem('reportArray');
        console.log(selected_lp);

        var query = 'selected_lp=' + selected_lp;
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../inc/updatelponadvdash.php",
                data: { selected_lparr : selected_lp},
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {

                    return true;
                }
            });

    });
```

updatelponadvdash.php file

```
<?php
require_once 'inc.php';

$selected_lparr = json_decode($_POST['selected_lparr']);

   foreach($selected_lparr as $value){

      $dbData = $lploop->adv_lploops($value); 
   }
?>
```

Now, in the chrome network tab, when I click the  and I `dump_var($selected_lparr)` the array is updated and I see the values like this:[image]

For some reason I get a 500 error.
As well I dont understand why the var_dump(inside the function below) dosent work. I seems that the function `adv_lploops` dosent get the variables. but i dont understand why.

This is the fuction I call:

```
public function adv_lploops($value){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `lptitels` WHERE titleidNo = '$value'";
    $row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Comment: url: "../inc/updatelponadvdash.php",  is correct ??  if use double dot means it will go back to parent directory .

Comment: Yes, it is, you can see in the image that the array appears in  `updatelponadvdash.php` file.

Comment: Turn on error reporting in your `updatelponadvdash.php`; 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1)` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. The output will probably explain what is wrong.

Comment: may be jquery-1.12.3.js  file is  not found .

Comment: You print `$_POST['selected_lparr']` or `$selected_lparr`

Comment: @Thakkie - This is the error i get. `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in /home/davdevco/public_html/tahat.co.il/inc/userclass.php on line 1467` in thet line is the end of the `adv_lploops` function.

Comment: @DavSev you aren't executing your sql query

Comment: after fixing the query as @madalinivascu suggested i get this two errors `[24-Apr-2017 05:20:08 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: User::$SELECT * FROM lptitels WHERE titleidNo = 45 in /home/davdevco/public_html/tahat.co.il/inc/userclass.php on line 1467
[24-Apr-2017 05:20:08 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in /home/davdevco/public_html/tahat.co.il/inc/userclass.php on line 1467` 45 is the first value in the php function. so the data arrives the array. why i keep getting the `fetch()` error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't executing the sql query, try the following:

```
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
$row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

note: you will need the $db object which is a connection to your database

Comment: Thank you! I didnt noticed it... fixed it

Comment: @DavSev seems that $db->prepare($sql); sees the sql as a static property of a class named User

Comment: This are the rows i fixed: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM `lptitels` WHERE titleidNo = '$value'";
        $row = $this->$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` how can i fix it in your opinion?

Comment: Try `$db->prepare( "SELECT * FROM `lptitels` WHERE titleidNo = '$value'")`

Comment: I changed to this `$sql = $this->dbh->query(".... `   and ` $row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` , and the error is gone, I even see the the function result in the 'updatelponadvdash.php' file.  why i dont see it in the frontend?

Comment: you don't see it in the front-end because you didn't output it, your success function doesn't append any data to the page

Comment: Thank you for all of your help! How do I return the data from the php file to the js file?  could you please point me to a tutorial or an exampel of how to do it?

Comment: in the success function you see a data param that data param is the Response text from your image, you simply append that data using ether jquery append()/html() or text() to your page, exp:`$('body').append(data);`